# Run a Python script once per day

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have a small Python utility script that I would like to run once a day, overnight when the computer is in a quiescent mode (hibernate, sleeping, whatever works). I have tried using Task Scheduler on Win10, but it just doesn't work- see all the Internet frustration.

Any suggestion welcome!

Comment: When the computer is hibernating or sleeping it doesn't run _any_ code

Answer (score 3):

You can configure Task Scheduler to wake your computer before it tries to run your task:

[image]